# How to make radio buttons write their label in several lines, is it possible?

Tags: radio-button, label

The best way to describe the problem is trough the following image

[image: long label]

It's very anti-estetic, can i limit the width of the label box, while forcing the text to spread in lines below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to set the Autosize property of the RadioButton to false and resize the control. The text will spread over multiple lines. 
Alternatively you can insert "\n" in the text - works only at run-time